# Android layout: distinguishing an 800x480 large device from a 1024x600 tablet

Tags: android-layout, android

Is there a way using Android layout to automatically distinguish between f/ex a Dell Streak with 800x480 resolution, and a Galaxy Tab or HTC Flyer with 1024x600 resolution? They all (presumably including the Flyer) report as -large (unlike the Xoom which reports as -xlarge). Is there a better layout tag than -large?

(Edited to clarify that -xlarge is no use in this case)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See the "Table 2" in [Supporting Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)
and try to combine Size and Density qualifiers together.
Also useful application [ScreenInfo](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.jotabout.screeninfo&feature=search_result)

Еxample:

Nexus One (480*800, 240 dpi) - "**layout-hdpi**" (normal screen, high density)

Samsung Galaxy Tab(600*1024, 169 ppi/dpi) - "**layout-large-mdpi**" (large screen, medium density)

Dell Streak(480*800, 186 dpi) - ??? (normal/large? screen, medium/high? density)

[image]

Comment: Thanks. We ended up using layout-large-v11 since this gives us Honeycomb devices with large screens including e.g. the Flyer once it's upgraded to HC - and it includes the Xoom and Tab 10.1 since the xlarge devices fall back to large if xlarge is not explicitly specified. The mdpi qualifier is a good idea, though - large-mdpi should exclude the 5" Streak.

Answer (score 6):

For a tablet the xlarge screensize was introduced in API9. So if you want a special layout for xlarge(tablets) screens you'd put it in a `layout-xlarge` directory.

Comment: xlarge is no use in this case - the Xoom reports as layout-xlarge - but this doesn't help with things like the Galaxy Tab and HTC Flyer which report as layout-large not layout-xlarge. So the question remains unanswered. Any more thoughts?